# Cloud Tasks - Create Task - Error: No connection established, code: 14

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have multiple services on GCP app engine that communicate to each other using google tasks. And one of the queues I have this error when I tried to create a new task:

[image: Error message]

This only appears when I left the services unused for a few hours but the problem disappear when I re-deploy the app engine service witch creates the task. And then, the problem comes back again.

If I tried to create a new task using the gcloud command line tool it works. No connection error.

I have two queues with the same setup and only this one have this problem.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a general issues relating to Google Client Libraries - [github issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1064)

Comment: Yes, Jan seems to be correct. 
As far as i've seen a workaround is to require grpc, the issue seems to happen because grpc-js is auto-required.

Try to downgrade node to v10.16.2 or v12.8.0

Or

[Require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-gax) grpc

Hope this helps.

Comment: I resolved this issue downgrading the @google-cloud/tasks (v1.4.0) which don't have a dependency with @grpc/grpc-js.